# Check if Ring is a Unique Factorization Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove that $\mathbb{Z}/p^q$, where $p$ is prime, is a UFD?

Well, I know that if $q=1$, it is because then it is a field.

Comment: If $q\neq 1$ then this is false, as the ring is not even an integral domain.

Comment: why it isn't an Integral Domain?

Comment: Please think a bit longer on this. Finding zero-divisors in the given ring is a good exercise that will really help you understand that ring.

Comment: okay, I understand. Thanks

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 3):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain if and only if $n$ is a prime (or $0$). In fact, this is one of the ways to define what it means for something to be a prime element of an arbitrary ring.

To be more specific, if $n = ab$ with both $a$ and $b$ strictly greater than $1$, then neither $a$ nor $b$ will be $0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but $ab = n = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

By a lucky coincidence, whenever $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, it is also a UFD (in fact a PID). This is because in that case, either $n$ is a prime, in which case the ring is finite, and any finite integral domain is a field (and clearly any field is a PID), or $n = 0$ in which case we are dealing with the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, which is an Euclidean domain (which implies that it is a PID).